# How to prevent two asynchronous processes running Concurrently - Speech To text Ionic / Angular app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, async-await, concurrency, speech-recognition

My SpeechTotext operation runs asynchronously.
Two separate textArea's can be updated  with the Speech to text function,  a variable is assigned to text within each textArea, and is later uploaded to a remote DB.

This is the SpeechToText async (ref [Cap-Community-SpeechTotext](https://github.com/capacitor-community/speech-recognition))  function:

```
     async startSpeechRecognition(textArea : string){
    // Start recording voice, esnure functionalty available first, pass the textArea writing to

    console.log("Eventmodal - SpeechRec called for textarea : " , textArea, "  called")
    const {available} = await SpeechRecognition.available();

    if (available && !this.recordingVoice) {
      this.recordingVoice = true;
      SpeechRecognition.start({
        popup: true, // Only for andrid and not reliable
        partialResults: true, // returns text as its spoken
        language: 'en-uk',
        //maxResults - dont need
      });

      SpeechRecognition.addListener('partialResults', (data : any) => {
        console.log("Event odal SpeechRec- txtearea = " , textArea);
        
        if (data.matches){
          if (textArea == "Reflection"){
            //update impact on prcative
            console.log("EventModal - SpecchToText BUTTON- txt area Learning Outcome/Reflection  called : ", textArea);
            this.uploadEvent.reflection = data.matches[0];
            this.specchToText = data.matches[0];
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
          }else {
            console.log("EventModal - SppechToText BUTTON- txt area Imapct on Practice/Learning Plan called ");
            this.uploadEvent.learningPlan = data.matches[0];
            this.specchToText = data.matches[0];
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
          }
        }

        // Android with capactort speech plugin 2.1. has a diffenret result type then 'matches', its 'val;ue
        if (data.value && data.value.lenght > 0) {
          this.specchToText = data.value[0];
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }

      })
    }
  }
```

This is one textArea (name=learningPlan) that can be updated, when button is clicked we pass a string representing  the textArea to update to the above function :

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label position = "floating">Imapct on Practice/Learning Plan   
      </ion-label>
      <ion-button (click)="startSpeechRecognition('learningPlan')" *ngIf="!recordingVoice">
        <ion-icon name="mic-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        Speak learning  plan
      </ion-button>
     
      <ion-textarea name="learningPlan"  maxlength="50000"   [(ngModel)]="uploadEvent.learningPlan" autocapitalize="sentences" 
      errorText="check" helperText="Looks good!" required="true"  rows="3" spellcheck="true" 
      placeholder="Think About : How have you integrated this learning into your practice? How has this learning made a difference to your capability and performance in your role? What have you learnt through completing this activity? How have your skills and knowledge improved or developed? How has this new learning / skilllset impacted on my capibilty in my current role?" autoGrow="true"  [counter]="true"
      ></ion-textarea>
      
    </ion-item>
```

This is the second textArea (name='Reflection') that can be updated, again we pass a string to the button to identify the textArea we want to update:

```
 <ion-button (click)="startSpeechRecognition('Reflection')" *ngIf="!recordingVoice">
        <ion-icon name="mic-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>


      <ion-label position = "floating">Learning Outcome/Reflection</ion-label>
      
      <ion-textarea name = "reflection" maxlength="50000"   [(ngModel)]="uploadEvent.reflection" 
      autocapitalize="sentences" errorText="check" helperText="How have my skills improved based on what I have learnt? " required="true"  
      rows="3" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Thinking about follwing criteria: What have you learnt through completing this activity? How have your skills and knowledge improved or developed?  " autoGrow="true"  
      [counter]="true"
      ></ion-textarea>

    </ion-item>
```

When either recording is complete, the stop button is executed:

```
<ion-button (click)="stopSpeechRecording()" color="danger" *ngIf="recordingVoice">
        <ion-icon name="mic-off-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        Stop Recording
      </ion-button>

async stopSpeechRecording(){
    // Stop voice recording 
    this.recordingVoice = false;
    await SpeechRecognition.stop();
    
  }
```

The order of the operations is difficult to trace, but they appear to occur concurrently.

If button A is pressed and operation A for TextArea  A ("Reflection') executes, and the operation is stopped, if user then selects button B for to update textArea B ('learningPlan'), both textAreas now update with the same value for textArea B, I believe  its because the process are running asynchronously / simultaneously.

Is there anyway I can prevent these two asynchronous  processes from running concurrently  ?

**Code Output in Xcode console:**

*This is the output when Button A for textArea A (Reflection) is executed:*

[log] - Event odal SpeechRec- txtearea =  Reflection
⚡️  [log] - EventModal - SpecchToText BUTTON- txt area Learning Outcome/Reflection  called :  Reflection
⚡️  TO JS {"matches":["Learning"]}
⚡️  [log] - Event odal SpeechRec- txtearea =  Reflection
⚡️  [log] - EventModal - SpecchToText BUTTON- txt area Learning Outcome/Reflection  called :  Reflection
⚡️  TO JS {"matches":["Learning out"]}
⚡️  [log] - Event odal SpeechRec- txtearea =  Reflection
⚡️  [log] - EventModal - SpecchToText BUTTON- txt area Learning Outcome/Reflection  called :  Reflection
⚡️  TO JS {"matches":["Learning outcome"]}
⚡️  [log] - Event odal SpeechRec- txtearea =  Reflection
⚡️  [log] - EventModal - SpecchToText BUTTON- txt area Learning Outcome/Reflection  called :  Reflection
⚡️  To Native ->  SpeechRecognition stop 33972943
⚡️  TO JS undefined
AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:2,706 CADefaultDeviceAggregate-27070-1: Abandoning I/O cycle because reconfig pending (1).
⚡️  TO JS {"matches":["Learning outcome"]}
⚡️  [log] - Event odal SpeechRec- txtearea =  Reflection
⚡️  [log] - EventModal - SpecchToText BUTTON- txt area Learning Outcome/Reflection  called :  Reflection
HALB_MachPort.cpp:174  HALB_MachPort::DestroyPort: not going to destroy anything this way

*And then button B for learningPlan- note the 'reflection' reference* :

[log] - Event odal SpeechRec- txtearea =  Reflection
⚡️  [log] - EventModal - SpecchToText BUTTON- txt area Learning Outcome/Reflection  called :  Reflection
⚡️  [log] - Event odal SpeechRec- txtearea =  learningPlan
⚡️  [log] - EventModal - SppechToText BUTTON- txt area Imapct on Practice/Learning Plan called

Comment: not sure that you want to add an event listener each time you click a button... that SpeechRecognition.addListener call seems like it should only happen on init.

Comment: There is a removeAllListeners() in the docs which returns a promise, might try call it in StopSpeechRecording()

Comment: @pcalkins That was the answer, if you post as a answer I will accept it , thanks